# "Загрузка..." - какая это синтаксическая конструкция?

Tags: синтаксис

Можно ли считать слово "Загрузка..." на экране монитора назывным предложением? Или это неполное предложение (пропущено слово "идет")? Или это вовсе не предложение?

Comment: Я считаю так: просто изолированное слово без многоточия не является предложением. В конструкции "Загрузка... Пожалуйста, подождите..." "Загрузка..." - это неполное предложение. А когда просто написано "Загрузка..." - это какой случай? Это тоже неполное предложение? Насчет назывных предложений я сомневаюсь во всех этих случаях.

Comment: Вот [еще одно обсуждение](https://ask.fm/russian/threads/150382693436), может быть, оно поможет прийти к решению.

Comment: Что именно вас не устроило? Ответ справки предельно ясен. Одно и тоже предложение можно рассматривать с разных точек зрения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Справка" вам ответила предельно четко. В чем сомнения? "Слово "Загрузка" на экране монитора назвать номинативным никак нельзя. Поскольку основное значение номинативных предложений  - это наименования предмета, идеи его существования, бытия ( Синтаксис современного русского языка. Валгина Н.С.).

На экране монитора можно говорить о неполном предложении, поскольку там подразумевается слово "идет". [Идет] загрузка. При ином контексте слово "загрузка', возможно, окажется номинативным. Все решает контекст.

P.S. Если вы внимательно читали бы все ответы "справки" и приведенные ее ссылки, думаю,сомнения у вас не возникали бы.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Мне просто также в Справке отвечали,что это вовсе не предложение. До этого Aer высказал точку зрения, что это назывное предложение. Были сомнения. Вы все-таки рассматриваете запись "Загрузка..."  как предложение или не предложение?

Comment: @SergG, я рассматриваю как неполное предложение.

Comment: Спасибо. По вашему мнению, влияет ли наличие многоточия на трактовку, предложение это или нет? В случае, когда написано отдельное слово без знаков препинания, можно ли говорить о коммуникативной функции и предложении? Признаете ли Вы, что в данных случаях можно говорить о предложении  лишь условно?

Comment: @SergG, нет, многоточие в данном случае не влият на трактовку. Предложение без знаков препинания лишено коммуникативной функции.

Answer (score 3):

Предложение в грамматическом смысле — высказывание, сообщающее о чем-либо. Вполне нормально, когда всего лишь одно слово его образует. «Загрузка...», написанное на экране, действительно назывное предложение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне в Справочной службе ответили, что это не назывное предложение. https://ask.fm/russian/answers/150033207612 Как Вы относитесь к их точке зрения?

Comment: @SergG синтаксис — одна из самых непонятных вещей на свете, особенно если разбираться в его истории, методах и прочем. За всю свою жизнь он приобрел кучу разных школ и взглядов на язык — кто-то, например, ставил во главу угла предложение, кто-то — словосочетание. Пишу я это к тому, чтобы вы, видя разные объяснения всяких синтаксических вопросов, имели в виду возможность просто разных подходов к проблеме. Это же, в общем, касается и нашего случая.

Comment: @SergG конечно, со строго синтаксической точки зрения изолированное слово «Загрузка» неинтересно для изучения. Однако, верно следуя школьным определениям назывного предложения, мой ответ стоит признать правильным.

Comment: Спасибо. Вот [еще одно обсуждение](https://ask.fm/russian/threads/150382693436), может быть, оно поможет прийти к решению.

Comment: @SergG страшно представить, что может обозначать табличка на двери туалета с неполным предложением: «Загрузка»...